# Git - remapping file ownership recursively

Tags: git

I have to believe someone has encountered this before and can hopefully shed some light on the issue.  Our company has acquired another that also uses Git.  During the migration process the user accounts will be renamed using a new format.  The problem is, when we move the Git repository, the accounts referenced within the repository will not match up to the new user ids.

Is there a way to remap both the current files and the history of the repository to the altered ids when moving the Git repository over to my servers?  Thus far the only method I have found is used when remapping users when migrating from svn to git.

Answer (score 0):

I would *strongly discourage* trying to modify user names for historical commits. You would have to rewrite the entire history tree, causing problems for anybody who has ever cloned the repository in the past (nothing will merge without a lot of work).

Instead, accept the past as it is, get everybody to use the new format user names for future work, and move forward.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  I'm all for less pain so I'll stick with a hands off approach with regards to modifying the repository history.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about file ownership. Git doesn't track file ownership. The only mode bit it does track is the executable bit. Files are created owned by whatever user is creating the working tree.

If in fact you're talking about the author/committer info on each commit, that's a different matter. As Greg says, I would discourage you from trying to rewrite that information, as that will rewrite the entire history of the repository. If you really do want to do it, you can use a `git filter-branch` command coupled with the appropriate `--env-filter` script to do any mapping you want on the author/committer info.